# ¿Cómo puedo realizar correctamente un Code Test en mi proyecto?

Tags: c++

**¡Qué tal!**

Normalmente a la hora de estar realizando un código escuchamos que nos digan que realicemos un test al código (**Code Test**), pero:

> ¿A qué se refiere exactamente?
> ¿Nos referimos a probar nuestro programa que esté funcionando correctamente y no tener algún bug?
> De ser así, ¿cómo podemos tomar acciones adecuadamente ante ello?

Actualmente me encuentro en esta situación con mi proyecto de C++.

Comment: Checa [ask], ¿qué has investigado o intentado?

Comment: Es una muy buena pregunta, pero como en este lugar no permiten este tipo de preguntas quiza te la cierren. pero en resumen un `code test` es eso, **un codigo que prueba un codigo** por ejemplo tengo una funcion `sumar(a,b)` y debo de asegurarme que dicha funcion cumpla con su cometido que seria `a+b`. En la mayoria de los lenguajes exiten herramientas de prueba(TestTools) puedes buscarlos en tu buscador favorito. en caso de que no cierren tu pregunta te la respondo dentro de 2 dias.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias,@BetaM!

He investigado mediante referencias de profesionales, sin embargo; si realizo una búsqueda en Google no encuentro una respuesta concreta. Lo que he intentando actualmente es utilizar el código como si fuera un usuario promedio.

Comment: Si googleas test c++ te saldra informacion de sobra y como realizarlos. Pero un test debe ser aprobado o no, con un resultado esperado. Es bueno manejarse con test para mejorar el codigo y proximos cambios.

Comment: @Shassain Oh, ya! Muchísimas gracias, ahora me queda más claro y sí, me imaginé ese riesgo de que me cierren la pregunta.

Comment: @RamiroBarone No lo había buscado de esa manera, mayormente lo buscaba en general, pero muchísimas gracias por el dato, lo tomaré muchísimo en cuenta!

Comment: puedes ver https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/writing-unit-tests-for-c-cpp?view=vs-2019 creo que te serviria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al iniciar en el mundo de la programación nos hablan bastante de pruebas; pruebas `unitarias`, pruebas `funcionales`, pruebas de `caja blanca`, pruebas de `caja negra`, Pruebas de `regresión`, Pruebas de `aceptación` y muchas otras más. Y lo que encontramos en google es mucho texto que leer sin ningún ejemplo del cual podamos guiarnos.

Esto sucede debido a la amplia gama de lenguajes programación existentes, sin incluir framework e librerías, ya que:

> **`cada lenguaje de programación tiene sus propias herramientas de prueba`**.

Entonces esta respuesta estará guida según mi experiencia en pruebas. Además que utilizare `php` como lenguajes de programación, `phpUnit` para las pruebas unitarias y `dusk-phpunit` para las pruebas funcionales.

Tenemos una ambiente de trabajo donde generalmente nuestro código se vería así:

```
public function getlista(Request $request){
    $data=User::with("roles")->orderBy("nombre","asc")->get();
    $roles=Role::all();
    return response()->json([
        "users"=>$data,
        "roles"=>$roles
    ],200);
}
```

Una función que realiza cierta tarea,en este caso retornar usuarios de mi sistema en `formato json`

**¿como la pruebo?**
Resp: Como es php, lo mas común seria: entrar a un navegador, ingresar la `url` y verificar personalmente que todos los datos estén correctos, es decir: están los `users`?, están los roles?, el formato de `users` es el correcto?.

Y las posibles repuestas serian: "Si, todo funciona bien" ó "Oh! no, me salio un error".

Ahora imagina tener 1000 funciones.¿Tendrías que **repetir mil veces el proceso anterior**?, peor aun **cambiaste el proceso de una función**, ¿los que dependían de dicha función, seguirán funcionando?

Ambas preguntas y muchas mas se solucionan realizando `code test` ó `codigos de prueba`.

El siguiente código esta `phpUnit` y verifica el correcto funcionamiento de la anterior función:

```
public function testGetUsers()
{
    
    $response=$this->json("get","api/user?api_token=".$this->api_token());
    $response->assertStatus(200);
    $response->assertJsonStructure([
        "users"=>[
            "*"=>[
                "apmaterno", "appaterno", "cargo", 
                "created_at", "email", "foto", 
                "id", "nombre", "roles", 
                "status", "updated_at", "usuario"
            ],
        ],
        "roles"
    ]);

}
```

donde:

- realizo la petición `get`(visito la url): `$response=$this->json("get","api/user?api_token=".$this->api_token());`
- Espero que la conexión sea correcta: `$response->assertStatus(200);`
- Verifico la estructura de mi `json`: `$response->assertJsonStructure`, especifico que `users` es un array con los datos: `"apmaterno", "appaterno", "cargo" ..., etc.`.

Por ultimo ejecuto `phpUnit` para verificar si todas mis pruebas están bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y como veras el resultado tengo 3 pruebas y 26 afirmaciones las cuales se probaron en menos de un segundo(409ms).**Hasta aquí lo que llamo una prueba unitaria**

Exiten otros tipos de prueba como:

```
public function testBasicExample()
{
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
        $browser->visit('/')
                ->assertSee('Ingresar')
                ->assertSee('EMAIL:')
                ->assertSee('CONTRASEÑA:')
                ->type("email","omar@admin.com")
                ->type("password","omar")
                ->press("Ingresar")//#login
                ->assertPathIs($this->url.'/home')
                ->visit("/users")
                ->assertTitleContains("Vera Cruz | usuarios")
                ;
    });
}
```

Mira lo que hace al ejecutar el comando para la prueba:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por si acaso no movi ni un dedo después de ejecutar el comando:`php artisan dusk`. Esa fue una prueba funcional con `dusk-phpunit` también es parte de `php` y lo que hace es:

- vistar inicio=`visit('/')`
- afirmar que se ve el texto Ingresar=`assertSee('Ingresar')`
- afirmar que se ve el texto Email=`assertSee('EMAIL:')`
- afirmar que se ve el texto CONTRASEÑA=`assertSee('CONTRASEÑA:')`
- escribir `omar@admin.com` en el campo email=`type("email","omar@admin.com")`
- escribir `omar` en el campo password=`type("password","omar")`
- presionar el botton Ingresar = `press("Ingresar")`
- afirmar pagina resultante home = `assertPathIs($this->url.'/home')`
- visitar url user = `visit("/users")`
- afirmar que el titulo contiene "Vera Cruz | usuarios" = `assertTitleContains("Vera Cruz | usuarios")`

Esta prueba también se la puede hacer solo en consola y no es recomendable hacerlo abriendo el navegador, pero si que mola verlo en funcionamiento y se aprecia la funcionalidad de los `code test`.

Me gustaría mostrar mas ejemplos de código en lenguajes como `javascript` con `mocha` como herramienta, pero la respuesta ya se hizo larga y aun no respondo tus preguntas.

### Respondiendo tus preguntas

**¿A qué se refiere exactamente?**
`Code test` se refiere a un código que prueba un código. Cada lenguaje de programación tiene sus propias herramientas de prueba.

**¿Nos referimos a probar nuestro programa que esté funcionando correctamente y no tener algún bug?**
Es exactamente a lo que se refiere, pero no se la realiza manualmente, otra vez existen herramientas que nos ayudan a hacerlo mas rápido y en magnitud.

**¿cómo podemos tomar acciones adecuadamente ante ello?**
Y una vez mas, busca la mejor herramienta de testeo para tu lenguaje de programación favorita.